# Does encoding of the java program code influence the compilation?

Tags: java, encoding

The Oracle documentation states:

> -encoding encoding
>
> Set the source file encoding name, such as EUC-JP and UTF-8. If -encoding is not specified, the platform default converter is used.

I know that the platform default converter on Mac OS X is Mac Roman. But when I have my `.java` file encoded in UTF-8 and many other encoding, the code compiled successfully. I also tried to force `javac` to read UTF-8 and EUC-JP encoding from a Mac Roman encoded program code, and it also compiled successfully.

Why is this happening? I expect all of the above to fail.

Comment: If you're only using "basic" characters, the encoding won't make a lot of difference.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tested using a hello world document, but why is that? Doesn't different encoding use different binary strings to represent a character?

Comment: Because ASCII characters 32-127 (English letters, Arabic numerals, basic punctuation) are the same pretty much everywhere. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html. Try mixing things up with more complex characters and it will start to get interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile and run this code:

```
System.out.println("".length());
```

When the file is saved as UTF-8 and interpreted as such, it will print 2, since the smiley needs two `char`s to be stored.

When the file is interpreted as MacRoman, it will print 4, since the UTF-8 encoding is four bytes long.

(Note: You can use this code in a unit test to ensure the correct encoding.)

When you try this:

```
System.out.println('');
```

Compiling as MacRoman doesn’t even work.

So, as long as all the UTF-8 content is in string literals and comments, everything seems to work.